# Snowflake tasks combining CRON scheduling (set time) with NON-CRON scheduling (every minute)

Tags: cron, stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, task, schedule

Every hour, new data will be loaded in a table. As soon as that is ready I want to call a stored procedure.

Is it possible with Snowflake Tasks and Streams to schedule that starting every hour on the hour, check every minute if the table has new data and if it does, call a stored procedure and stop checking every minute?

At first I thougt about having 1 task with an hourly schedule. The next task would be scheduled every minute and have the hourly task as its predecessor. Unfortunately it is not possible for a task to have both a predecessor and a schedule. What would be a way to create this kind of scheduling?

For example

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TASK tsk_X_X_1
        WAREHOUSE = X
        SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 1 * * * UTC'  
        AS INSERT INTO XX.Test SELECT 'hourly', sysdate()
    ;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TASK tsk_X_X_2
        WAREHOUSE = X
        SCHEDULE = '5 minutes' 
        AFTER TASK tsk_X_X_1
        As INSERT INTO XX.Testing SELECT '5min', sysdate()
    ;
```

Error: Task TSK_X_X_2 cannot have both a schedule and a predecessor.

Comment: Have you looked into the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA function? You can have a task check that and run or not run depending on whether or not the stream has data: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_stream_has_data.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, starting at for example 8.00am I was hoping task 2 could check every minute to see if the table has been updated using the stream as a condition. I'm interested in stopping the task to check every minute after  a table has been updated while every hour it resets to checking the stream every minute again.

Comment: I'm now testing having a start task scheduled at certain times. This first task will have a sql statement to resume a processing task. This second task will call a stored procedure if the condition shows that the stream has data and a schedule to run every mintue. A third task will suspend the processing task.

Comment: Has anyone tried that to see if that's possible? Secondly, is there a way to make sure the third task will have suspended the second task (that runs every minute with the stream condition) before the second task runs again?

Comment: You should not have to suspend the task as long as the task that ran is still running. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#task-scheduling. "If a task is still running when the next scheduled execution time occurs, then that scheduled time is skipped."